# android + sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11: error: package android.os does not exist

Tags: android, java-11

I'm trying to play with Java11 APIs in android application and failed to make it compile.

Steps to fail:

1. Using current version of Android Studio 4.1.2 - generated dummy project "Basic Activity"
2. Build & Launch - everything OK so far
3. Open `app/build.gradle` and set `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11` + `targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11`
4. In **Project Structure** > **SDK Location** > **JDK Location** - select path to JDK 11
5. Build ... and it fails with following error

```
FirstFragment.java:3: error: package android.os does not exist
```

So the question is - what am I doing wrong? What is missing to build the project with `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch to the latest version
[Android Studio Arctic Fox Canary 9 (2020.3.1.9) and AGP 7.0](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/03/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-9.html)

Comment: And it appears that major point is `build.gradle`:`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha09"` - and this newer version is only supported by Canary version of Android Studio ...

Comment: may you have some comments for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556819/android-corelibrarydesugaring-which-java-11-apis-can-i-expect-to-work