# Android with sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11 gives error error: "package android.app does not exist"

Tags: android-studio

When using the JDK 11 target, then I get this error:

> error: package android.app does not exist

**I saw a solution** [to upgrade to the 'Canary' AS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551892/android-sourcecompatibility-javaversion-version-11-error-package-android-os). I prefer to use the beta or stable Android Studio version. I have updated it regularly. Not planning a major change for just an upgrade.

So, this works well: even with an Android Studio "Project settings" and "JDK" with "JDK 11".

When the build.gradle has these compile options, everything works fine.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

This gives the mentioned errors:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

My build.grade project file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}
```

Parts of my build.grade module file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}
```

How can I build normally using the (Oracle) JDK 11 compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just receive the Android Studio / Gradle 7 upgrade.

Everything is working right now!

1. Use this as your compiler options:

> ```
> compileOptions {
>     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
>     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
> }
> ```

2. In the settings you see that the JDK 11 is already chosen. If not chosen automatically, you will be allowed to chose that JDK 11 version.

[image]

Comment: Any idea what the underlying problem was?